# Why does my var call not return DataListItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Ever since getting Resharper I've been a fan of using var inside methods wherever possible. So later if you pass in a different type the change cascades down through your code without having to change every int declaration to a double.
Which brings me to my question. I'm retrieving a list of DataListItems from a DataList

```
var daysWorked = dlResourcesAllocated.Items;
```

Then stepping through the List it returns

```
foreach (var d in daysWorked)
{
     var c = d.FindControl("ucSomethingSomething"); //Doesn't compile d has no methods
}
```

And my d is suddenly cast to an Object that has no methods

```
foreach (DataListItem d in daysWorked)
{
     var c = d.FindControl("ucSomethingSomething");
}
```

However works just fine.

I'm just curious how come "var" can't figure out it's a collection of DataListItem. Intellisense seems to know it.
I'm sure there's a perfectly simple one liner explanation for this. The skeet dude is probably gonna show up and point out I shoulda paid better attention when reading C# in depth...

Comment: If you do `var daysWorked = dlResourcesAllocated.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()` It'll work since it will return a generic collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because [`DataListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitemcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DataListItem>`, as it predates generics.

Since it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, the runtime uses `Object` in your `foreach` loop *unless you explicitly provide the type*.

By writing this:

```
foreach (var d in daysWorked)
```

The compiler sees that `daysWorked` implements `IEnumerable`, and rewrites this as:

```
foreach (object d in daysWorked)
```

When using `foreach` with `IEnumerable` (non-generic), you are allowed to provide the type explicitly:

```
foreach (DataListItem d in daysWorked)
```

Doing this effectively casts the results from the `IEnumerable` for you, providing the proper type in your loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you *could* use `foreach(var d in daysWorked.Cast<DataListItem>())` but that's kinda gross.

Comment: @JonSkeet True - but that's really running it through another method to do it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, hey man. I just reread my question. What I meant to say is, I love your book and it's really good at explaining this kinda stuff.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks dude, that explained it really well.

Comment: @MikeyMouse: :) In fact I don't think it *does* explain what `var` does for a `foreach` loop... one time when it's worth looking at the spec instead!

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, if the 4.5 or 5.0 in depth explains that specifically I'll be printing out a copy of this question and hanging it on my wall ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `DataList.Items` returns a `DataListItemCollection`, not a generic collection of `DataListItem`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitemcollection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest that you only use `var` when it's dead obvious what the type is. If you need to think, you're probably causing more harm than you're helping.

It would appear that the `Item` property returns and `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerable<DataListItem>`, this means that the items in the enumeration are of type `object`.

`foreach (DataListItem d in daysWorked)` will actually result in a cast from the type returned by each item in `daysWorked` to `DataListItem`, which is why that code works correctly.